# How to disable edit_line

Tags: ruby, user-interface, shoes

I would like to disable a text input field (`edit_line` in Shoes) for user edition(grey field).
I want to have possibility to e.g. set text but I dont want to give that possibility to users.
I checked manual but there's nothing about that `edit_line`, only basics.

Comment: Context? Code? What is "user(grey field)"? "edit_line"?

Comment: well in html it's disabled attribute in input. In java setEnabled(false) on textField and I dont know how it works in Shoes

Comment: @Dominik. Give some context or this question is likely to be closed. What are you trying to do? Which gems are you using? What is 'Shoes'?

Comment: Try edit_line(state: "disabled")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered in the comments session, to disable `edit_line` you need to pass a `state` option:
`edit_line(state: "disabled")`

Answer (score 2):

Above answers are perfectly valid! But incase you want to toggle between enabled and disabled state after the edit_line object is created, you can use:

```
@line = edit_line
@line.state = "disabled" #Disables @line
@line.state = "enabled" #Enables @line back!
```