# How to provide read-only mode in edit_box in Shoes

Tags: ruby, shoes

So, How to provide read-only mode in edit_box? I can't find it.
Or is there another solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095586/how-to-disable-edit-line/25098751#25098751

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found needed option for readonly state! It is so trivially :)

```
 :state => "readonly"
```